# Angular 11 - how to isolate routes

Tags: angular

In lack of a better headline, this is the use case:
Having:

```
App-module/routing/Component
Userhandler-module/routing/component
Login-component
NewUser-component
```

expected: calling http://localhost/userhandler should redirect to: http://localhost/userhandler/login and load LoginComponent at outlet: userhandling

actual: Redirects to http://localhost/userhandler, and reloads UserHandlerComponent at PRIMARY

App-component.html:

```
<div style="text-align:center"class="container">
  <h1>
    Welcome {{title}}!
  </h1>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App-module:

```
...
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 ...
 ],
 imports: [
 AppRoutingModule,
 ... 
 ],
```

App-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserHandlerComponent } from "./user-handler/user-handler.component";
//import {UserHandlerModule  } from "./user-handler/user-handler.module";
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/userhandler', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'userhandler', component: UserHandlerComponent, loadChildren: () => import('./user-handler/user-handler.module').then(m => m.UserHandlerModule)},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes/*, {useHash: true}*/)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

user-handler.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {UserHandlerComponent  } from "./user-handler.component";
import { UserHandlerRoutingModule} from "./user-handler-routing.module";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [UserHandlerComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, UserHandlerRoutingModule],
  exports: [UserHandlerComponent],
})
export class UserHandlerModule { }
```

user-handler-routing.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent} from "../login/login.component";
import { NewAccountComponent } from "../new-account/new-account.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/userhandler/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, outlet: 'userhandling', pathMatch: 'prefix' },
  { path: 'new', component: NewAccountComponent, outlet: 'userhandling' },
  
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserHandlerRoutingModule {}
```

user-handler.component.html:

```
div class="top">
    <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowheight="20px">
        <mat-grid-tile cols="1">
            
        </mat-grid-tile>
        <div class="logininfo">
        <mat-grid-tile cols="2">
            <router-outlet name="userhandling"></router-outlet>
        </mat-grid-tile>
        </div>
    </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

All the shown are snippets for readability.

How can I stack the routes, but keep the routing isolated and handling by the responsive module(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update,

Well, to answer my own question, I need to generate a new module and handle all the routing in that module. So example the module user-handler-module has a user-handler-routing-module, that handles all the routing for the user-handler (login, auth, redirect, etc)